# negated / inverted character class fails to match square bracket in perl

Tags: regex, perl

In the syntax below, following [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Negation),
I would expect every character not in the Latin 26-letter alphabet to be transformed into underscore `_`.

But instead, the square bracket is not recognized as being in this character class, as we see:

```
> printf '%s' 'dog[-1]cat' | perl -p -e 'use strict; use warnings; s/[^A-za-z]/_/g;'; echo;
dog[__]cat
> perl --version

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 4 (v5.18.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

To get what I want, I have to **explicitly** mention the square brackets, like this:

```
> printf '%s' 'dog[-1]cat' | perl -p -e 'use strict; use warnings; s/[^A-za-z]/_/g; s/[\[\]]/_/g;'; echo;
dog____cat
```

The concept of negation/inversion seems simple; what am I missing?

And is there a more elegant say to achieve what I want, for instance without using two sequential substitutions?

Comment: `s/[^[:alpha:]]/_/g;'` does it but I can't explain why your version doesn't work so I won't write an answer :-)

Comment: Ha, I missed the lowercase `z`. There are some advantages to using the predefined character classes like `[:alpha:]` :-)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character set `[^A-za-z]` includes `A-z` and not `A-Z` -- that is, it includes everything in ASCII between the capital `A` and lowercase `z`, including the punctation between `Z` and `a`:

```
⋮
X
Y
Z
[
\
]
^
_
`
a
b
c
⋮
```

Changing `[^A-za-z]` to `[^A-Za-z]` should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

My error was twofold.

1. a careless error inside the hand-written character, as pointed out by responders
2. my ignorance of the `[:alpha:]` posix class (also thanks to responders), although I had seen it many times, just never learned it

```
~/u/kh/bin> echo 'dog[-1]cat' | perl -p -e 'use strict; use warnings; s/[^A-Za-z]/_/g;'; echo;
dog____cat_
~/u/kh/bin> echo 'dog[-1]cat' | perl -p -e 'use strict; use warnings; s/[^[:alpha:]]/_/g;'; echo;
dog____cat_
~/u/kh/bin>
```